# SocketIO.Server Object disappears when installing socket.io

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io

I want to create a Socket.io server in nodejs however, the `io` object created via `const io = require('socket.io')({});` just returns `const io: any` without any properties or methods and I can't seem to connect to the server. The weird thing is, when I remove the node module via `npm remove socket.io` the `io` object returns `const io: SocketIO.Server` with all its properties and methods. But when I try to run it, I get an error message saying missing module, which is expected since the module is not installed.

I just don't understand what is going on.

Any help is appreciated :D

```js
const io = require('socket.io')({path:'/socket'});

io.listen(3400);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("Connection");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but I did not succeed. When adding a `console.log(io)` to the end of your code the object output looks as expected. Therefore your server should be running.

My Output:

```
Server {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _nsps: Map {
    '/' => Namespace {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      sockets: Map {},
      _fns: [],
...
```

You might be confusing your code editors inaccurate type detection for the actual value of the variable. VSCode detected `const io: any` for me too, even though the socket server is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I guess my problem is the client then. Still I am not able to see any methods and properties of the io Object eventhough everyone in the tutorials is able to see them and use the autocompletion. Maybe my issue is more concerning VSCodes IntelliSense.

Comment: Is this problem solved now in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201814/cant-connect-to-socket-io-nodejs-server) of yours?