# Can't connect to Socket.io nodejs server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is the code of the Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

http = http.createServer(app).listen(3400,() => {
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('connection');
    });
});
```

I am using the Socket.io Client Test Tool: https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/

When I enter the address `http://myWANIP:3400` as the URL and hit connect, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated :D

Edit: The Host is behind a NAT and the port 3400 is being forwarded (TCP).

Edit2: After some helpful comments I changed the code to:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3400);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connection');
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the pertinent information regarding the networking setup at play here. Where is the script being hosted? Is that host behind a NAT? Is the NAT/port forwarding configured properly?

Comment: @esqew Yes the host is behind a NAT. The port is getting forwarded.

Comment: Do NOT use the same `http` variable to mean multiple things.  That's just confusing and bad coding.  The result of `http.createServer()` is a server object and that variable should be named something like `server`.

Comment: Nothing happens when you do `http://myWANIP:3400` because the web server you have on that port doesn't do anything visible when it receives a request.  Your code is very misguideded to attempt to start a new socket.io server on EVERY incoming http request.  That's just wrong.  It's hard to say what the correct code is because you don't describe what you're really trying to accomplish here.  If you're just trying to start a socket.io server, then remove that code from inside of the `http.createServer()` callback so it's at the top level and you only call it once on server startup.

Comment: @jfriend00 I changed it to be `var server = http.createServer...`

Comment: @jfriend00 the line `console.log("connection")` should get triggered when I try to connect to the server, right?

Comment: @MindStudio - Only when you try to make a programmatic socket.io connection to the server, not when you go to `http://myWANIP:3400` in your browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228718/discussion-between-mindstudio-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code block looks more appropriate.  We can't really tell if your NAT and port forwarding is set up correctly, but if it is, then you should be able to make a socket.io connection from a web page with this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
const socket = io("http://myWANIP:3400", {transports: ["webSocket"]});
</script>
```

And, when that connection occurs, you should see the results of `console.log('connection');` in the server logs.

Another way to verify that your NAT and port forwarding is working correctly is to add this to your server:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
     console.log("got web page request");
     res.send("hello");
});
```

Then, when you got to `http://myWANIP:3400`, in the browser, you should get a log on your server and a response page back that says "hello".

Comment: I added the GET request handler and I am able to see the "hello" in my browser. But I still am not able to get a socket.io connection. Do I need to forward more than just TCP on that port?

Comment: Secondly, `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` would require the socketio client to be present on that server and not just this in an index.html file, right? Since I am planning to use the dart client https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client in a flutter app I tried it using that, but it still failed to trigger the connection event.

Comment: Well, the `<script>` tag client example assumed you were connecting from a web page served by your web server.  The socket.io client is automatically served from any socket.io server.  If that's not the case (you're connecting from some other type of client), then you would obviously use that other client to make the connection.